# Efficient looping through AS3 dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, iterator, iteration

```
for (var k in dictionary) 
{
  var key:KeyType = KeyType(k);
  var value:ValType = ValType(dictionary[k]); // <-- lookup
  // do stuff
}
```

This is what I use to loop through the entries in a dictionary. As you can see in every iteration I perform a lookup in the dictionary. Is there a more efficient way of iterating the dictionary (while keeping access to the key)?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Iterate through **keys** & **values**:

```
for (var k:Object in dictionary) {
    var value:ValType = dictionary[k];
    var key:KeyType = k;
}
```

Iterate through **values** more concisely:

```
for each (var value:ValType in dictionary) {

}
```

Comment: I need to know the key (clarified in my question)

Comment: Accepted because it answers the question. As a solution though, I've made a wrapper around dictionary which stores the key and value as value of its dictionary.

Answer (score -2):

In AS3 there are 3 different `for` loops, you should use one that suits your needs best.

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or
>   worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and
>   these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact
>   when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about
>   small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization
>   is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities
>   in that critical 3%.
>
> Donald Knuth