# Getting Keys by values , in a dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I perform the following operations on a dictionary, provided all my values are unique and unsorted.

```
key : value
152 : 780
87 : 688
2165 : 15
```

- I want to get all keys.
- I want to find key for value 688
- I want to get all values.

Preferably, without a loop and without having to maintain the key-value relation in an external object.

I sometimes miss, python for these sort of things.

Comment: I think this is what you want, answered previously in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386793/efficient-looping-through-as3-dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keys are integer values, Array might help. It is a sparse array; so for and for each will only process keys that have been assigned a value (I have no idea about memory usage though).

So:

```
var list: Array = [];
list[1] = 10;
list[4] = 40;

for each(var value: int in list) trace(value);
// outputs (order can be different)
// 10
// 40

// index has to be * or String; the compiler gives an error if it is not
for(var index: * in list) trace(index);
// outputs (order can be different)
// 1
// 4
```

There is a indexOf method to get the key for a value; there is no simple function to get all keys though.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do any point you want without the cost of an iteration over your Dictionary. So maintaining another object seems to be what you need to do.