# get an array of Dictionary's keys

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a dictionary, where both keys and values are my own classes. How can I get an array of keys? How can I find out what keys are in this dictionary?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

look at the [link for action script](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=234938)

Just use for ios

```
NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys];
```

In general, if you wonder if a specific class has a specific method, **look up Apple's own documentation**. In this case, see [NSDictionary class reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Go through all the methods. You'll discover many useful methods that way.

Comment: @SentineL ok you didn't mentioned, take alook at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997199/getting-keys-by-values-in-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 6):

```
var dict = new Dictionary();

dict["a"] = 1;
dict["b"] = 2;
var arrResult: Array = new Array();

for ( var key: Object in dict )
{
    arrResult.push( key );
}

trace( arrResult ) -> b,a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lamda expression for the same. Here is the sample code for it.

```
Dictionary<string, string> Test = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Test.Add("Azhar","Mansuri");
            Test.Add("Azhar2", "Mansuri");
            Test.Add("Azhar3", "Mansuri");
            Test.Add("Azhar4", "Mansuri");
            Test.Add("Azhar5", "Mansuri");
            Test.Add("Azhar6", "Mansuri");

            string[] key = Test.Select(s => s.Key).ToArray();
```

key array will return all the keys of dictionary.

**Update :**
since you want to know the key there is no better way than this:

for (var k:Object in dictionary) 
{
  var value:ValType=dictionary[k];
  var key:KeyType=k;
 // do stuff
}

It is just a sample code. However it may be helpful for you.

Comment: What's wrong woth you? peaple?! :) I'm asking about ActionScript 3, but 1st of you giving answer on Objective-C, 2ns - on C#, 3rd - on C# too! Are you kidding me?! :)

Comment: You didn't mention that you wanted to make it in ActionScript 3 in your question.Please check my modified answer.