# Dictionary uses values as keys

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary

--Or so it seems. Confused about the AS3 Dictionary. I have this:

```
map = new Dictionary();
map["someKey"] = 1;
```

And I try to print it out in two ways:

```
for each( var key:Object in d ) {
    trace( key + ": " + d[key] );
}
```

This prints `1: undefined`

```
for each( var o:Object in d ) {
    var key:String = o.toString();
    var val:int = d[o];
    trace( key + ": " + val );
}
```

This prints `1: null`

I would expect that it comes out as `someyKey: 1`. Am I just printing it out wrong?

Comment: It seems like the dictionary does not confuse keys and values, it just chooses to give you values when you iterate over it. Surely there's an alternative way to iterate that yields the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in [Efficient looping through AS3 dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386793/efficient-looping-through-as3-dictionary) you loop though it the wrong way. You should be doing:

```
for ( var key:Object in d ) {
    trace( key + ": " + d[key] );
}
```

Comment: Ahh, so it was just the 'each', had to stare for a moment to catch it. That makes a lot of sense, thanks.